# Holographic universe experiment?

Tags: experimental-physics, holographic-principle

I heard a passing news story which a satellite employed to prove or disprove the [Holographic Universe theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=holographic+universe+theory) came back disproving the Holographic Universe Theory.  I searched for recent news reports and have not found any.  Can someone comment or answer any sources of this news or how ongoing experiments are going.

Comment: The holographic universe is a completely unconfirmed hypothetical model. It is one of hundreds, if not thousands of suggested models and it exemplifies the deep crisis of early 21st century theoretical physicists who, in reaction to missing data, have begun to replace solid theoretical work with speculation. I can't blame them, but I wouldn't take any of this seriously, either.

Comment: I am aware of Fermilabs Holometer experiment, this news story I thought I heard was something different or I may be delusional.

Comment: There are, for instance, third party analyses of gamma-ray and x-ray satellite data which seem to rule out naive models of the Planck scale on electromagnetic waves, which may also remove the holographic models from the set of likely candidates. Like I said... the problem starts with the models, which can't even return firm predictions at the TeV scale. Lacking that people will augment them with handwaving models that can be tested. So now you have one speculative model pitted against another in some corner case of observational data... I wouldn't pay too much attention, at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermilab conducted the [Hogan's holometer experiment](http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/breaking/2010/10/20/fermilab-scientists-to-test-hypothesis-of-holographic-universe) on the smallest scales of the space fabric

the report is available in arxiv :
[Search for Space-Time Correlations from the Planck Scale with the Fermilab Holometer](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01216)

> Measurements are reported of high frequency cross-spectra of signals
>   from the Fermilab Holometer, a pair of co-located 39 m, high power
>   Michelson interferometers. The instrument obtains differential
>   position sensitivity to cross-correlated signals far exceeding any
>   previous measurement in a broad frequency band extending to the 3.8
>   MHz inverse light crossing time of the apparatus. **A model of universal
>   exotic spatial shear correlations that matches the Planck scale
>   holographic information bound of space-time position states is
>   excluded to 4.6 $\sigma$ significance**.

Comment: as you see, results are mainly negative. But the relevance of the experiment is debatable and the efficiency of the mathematical abstraction is not disputed :)